# Angular - Data binding on reused components

Tags: angular

I am updating model value which need to reflects on html which used mutliple times(component reusability).

**app.component.html**

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
```

**hello.component.html**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" /> 
<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>
```

[image]

### Scenario

- So i have enter value in Block1 **input text box**, same value
  should get reflect on Block2 **input textbox** immediatley.

**Note:** *Simple approach of code require to do the fix.*

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f6yzty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A mutable object can be used on this approach for simple fix. Object
>   Variable defined in parent component and it can be accessed to child
>   through `@Input` decorator.

**app.component.ts**

```
 name = {
    value: 'Angular'
 }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<p> Block1</p>
<hello [name]="name"></hello>
<p> Block2</p>
<hello [name]="name"></hello>
```

**hello.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name.value" />
  <h1>Hello {{name.value}}!</h1>
  `
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: any;
}
```

Then it can be modified in both reused components.

Updated fixes on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3sbzjl)

Answer (score 1):

#### Service and BehaviorSubject

You could use a service which stores the value of your input, and a `BehaviorSubject`.

Service file :

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  value: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('');

  setValue(newValue: string) {
    this.value.next(newValue);
  }
}
```

in **hello.component.ts** :

```js
constructor(private appService: AppService) {  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.appService.value.subscribe((newValue) => this.uname = newValue);
  }

  update() {
    this.appService.setValue(this.uname);
  }
```

and `update()` method should be triggered using `ngModelChange` in your hello.component.html :

```html
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="uname" (ngModelChange)="update()" />
```

Here is a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3hfhsn)

---

#### Output and EventEmitter

You can also use an Output which updates a global value stored in your parent component.

In **hello.component.ts**:

```js
@Input() uname: string;
@Output() unameUpdt: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
  
updated() {
  this.unameUpdt.emit(this.uname);
}
```

**app.component.ts** :

```js
unameFromParent = '';

updateGlobalValue(value) {
  this.unameFromParent = value;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<hello [uname]="unameFromParent" (unameUpdt)="updateGlobalValue($event)"></hello>
<hello [uname]="unameFromParent" (unameUpdt)="updateGlobalValue($event)"></hello>
```

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3ttm9b)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any other approach without service?

Comment: In Angular, services are used to store and share data between components. I understand it could look overkilled here but I think this is the way to go.
However you could also use an `@Output`. I will try to post an other answer

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, do you have any idea on change detection startegy can solve the issue?